# PFSense enable private access via shell

Tags: shell, pfsense

I was setting up a new PFSense and I managed to tick "Block private networks and loopback addresses" on the LAN interface. Is there a shell command through which I can disable that?
I know I'm supposed to be editing /cf/config.xml I think but I don't know what the syntax is to even start a text editor on PFSense?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

PFSense 2.4.4_2 is the version and I have no other LAN interfaces assigned...

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I managed to do pfctl -d to disable the firewall and then it let me in and I edited the rule as required.

Now all I need is to re-enable the firewall...